# Entity Framework Cannot access a disposed context instance - but works called from external controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

Handling a transaction in a controller, I have a function in my 'accountsHelpers' lib to mark a payment as paid. It was geting heavy in the controller so I created a  'processReceipt' function in the 'accountsHelpers' to keep the controllers light. This is academic but provides a context.

After moving creating the 'processReceipt' function in the helpers, I see it no longer worked because when it calls the 'MarkTransactionAsPaid' function in the same helper lib, I get this error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException
> HResult=0x80131622
> Message=Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

It is a bit odd, because I have modified the function to do nothing but find the object and save changes... like this:

```cs
public async Task<InfoBool> MarkTransactionAsPaid(
    int paymentId, string pspReference, string receiptId)
{
    try
    {
        MoneyTransaction? foundtransaction =
            await _context.MoneyTransactions
                .Where(p => p.Id == paymentId)
                .Include(p =>p.User)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

       ... // do stuff    
   
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The transaction is found just fine, but the SaveShanges immediately after causes the error even if I remove all the 'do stuff' code...

I have seen various references to this in here and most solutions seem to resolve with a missing 'await' or functions returning Void on async... I don't think this is the issue here and maybe revolves around my understanding (or lack) of the dependency injection.

This is the calling code:

```cs
try
{
    if (receipt.result == "Success")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(receipt.originalReceiptId)) // Then this is a payment
        {
            var paymentId = int.Parse(receipt.consumer.yourConsumerReference);
            InfoBool res = await _accountsHelpers.MarkTransactionAsPaid(paymentId, receipt.yourPaymentReference, receipt.receiptId);
            if (!res.Success)
            {
... etc
```

In my accountsHelpers I am injecting the DBContext as follows: (simplified slightly)

```cs
public AccountsHelpers(
    IMapper mapper,
    RGDbContext context,
    IConfiguration settings, 
    IAzureHelpers azureHelpers)

    public AccountsHelpers(
    IMapper mapper,
    RGDbContext context,
    IConfiguration settings, 
    IAzureHelpers azureHelpers)
{
    _mapper = mapper;
    _context = context;
    _settings = settings;
    _logger = logger;
    _azureHelpers = azureHelpers;
}
```

In my program.cs and adding the AccountsHelpers as follows:

```cs
//AccountsHelpers
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccountsHelpers, AccountsHelpers>();
```

Previsously, I was handling the receipt processing in the controller and when calling the function from there it worked fine.

```cs
InfoBool res = await _accountsHelpers.MarkTransactionAsPaid(
    paymentId,
    paymentResult.receipt.yourPaymentReference,
    paymentResult.receipt.receiptId);
    
if (!res.Success)...
```

I am unclear where I am calling 'dispose' I did wonder if it could be the try catch blocks in both functions? But don't really see that. Also wondering if it is something in the way I have set up the DI...

I have worked around this for now by moving the `ProcessReceipt` function back to the controller... But I would like to understand this and also, the code is a bit too heavy for the controller really. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for 'editing' my question Steven ... Do you have anything useful to add?

Comment: Just trying to understand the logic In `MarkTransactionAsPaid` , I see you query for a transaction and proceed to call `SaveChangesAsync`, but what changes/modifications were done to the transaction?

Comment: @BrettJB: There must be some crucial details missing from your question, because I see no reason why the `DbContext` would get disposed of from under your feet. Can you turn your question into a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? i.e. an example that contains the minimum amount of code that reproduces the issue, but is a fully working program that we (ideally) can copy/paste and run locally? Please add a comment when you done this.

Comment: Usual cases with this exception: 1) forgot `await` in some place 2) Retuned in some function `IQueryable/IEnumerable` and materialized objects after disposing context.

Comment: Sorry @DenisMicheal,  I removed the intervening code to illustrate that it was nothing to do with anything between the find and save. Sorry if that wasn't clear... The code just changes the transaction from pending to paid.

Comment: What code is calling MarkTransactionAsPaid? is that call awaited? Are you attempting to use any parallelization? Is there any code anywhere in your system that is disposing of any DbContext instance, injected or otherwise? Code that disposes an injected DbContext would be the prime culprit, if you have any lines of code that dispose a DbContext I would be putting breakpoints there and running the application without any other breakpoints to if a potentially shared instance would be disposed. What you show does not explain the problem which means the problem lies where you don't expect it.

Comment: I have added the bit of code that calls the MarkTransactionAsPaid, this is awaited.